# Referencing pages with no properties in Liquid conditionals for Shopify store

Tags: shopify, liquid

I successfully implemented a slider that shows different content on each page of a Shopify store. Out of the five pages where I would like to put unique content (an about page, a blog feed, another manually added static content page, the homepage, and the catalog page), I can't provide unique content for the homepage and the catalog page because I can't reference them in liquid.

I created a test snippet to show all potentially useful variables in order to discover a means of referencing my pages in a conditional:

```
<div class="grid__item__nm--wrap">
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE PAGE HANDLE IS:</h1> {{ page.handle }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE PAGE TITLE IS:</h1> {{ page.title }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE PAGE TEMPLATE SUFFIX IS:</h1> {{ page.template_suffix }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE PAGE ID IS:</h1> {{ page.id }}</span>
</div>
```

(Note: The above snippet works fine and doesn't need troubleshooting. I post it as a succinct way to demonstrate what I'm doing.)

Including this snippet in **theme.liquid** works for all the pages I added to the navigation and for the "About Us" page, showing the different propertiers. However, nothing is output for any of the properties on the homepage or the catalog page.

The best I can do is to show the same content on the homepage and catalog page through the "else" case. This is not good enough. I want different content for the homepage and catalog page. In fact, ideally I would like to exclude the catalog page (but not the homepage) from the inclusion of the snippet that generates the slider. I don't know how to do either of those things without having any properties to use for referencing the catalog page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Shopify schema, a page is something with the url as follow - `//mystorelink.com/pages/page-handle` . So when you use `{{ page.title }}` it will display the page title only when the url is in the above format.

Don't confuse between a "Shopify page" and a "webpage" for both are completely different.

A Shopify page is a template while a webpage is a normal html page. In order for your requirement refer to following link types and templates

1. `/` or `//myshoplink.com` -> index.liquid -> `{{ page_title }}` & `{{ page_description }}`
2. `/collections/xyz` -> collection.liquid -> `{{ collection.title }}` & `{{ collection.description }}`
3. `/products/xyz` or `/collections/abc/products/xyz` -> product.liquid -> `{{ product.title }}` & `{{ product.description }}`
4. `/pages/xyz` -> page.liquid -> `{{ page.title }}` & `{{ page.description }}`

etc similarly for other templates.

**P.S. You can have multiple product/collection/pages etc. templates using suffix values, but `{{ <template>.title }}` remains the same**

**P.P.S. If nothing is to be changed you can plainly use `{{ page_title }}` and `{{ page_description }}` everywhere. It defaults to the template currently in use.**

Comment: Thanks. I was badly confused about the relationship between Shopify templates and rendered pages.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else, here is a more comprehensive testing snippet for finding identifiers to use in Liquid conditionals, based on the accepted answer:

```
<div class="grid__item__nm--wrap">
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY PAGE TITLE IS:</h1> {{ page.title }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY PAGE HANDLE IS:</h1> {{ page.handle }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY PAGE TEMPLATE SUFFIX IS:</h1> {{ page.template_suffix }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY PAGE ID IS:</h1> {{ page.id }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE RENDERED PAGE TITLE:</h1> {{ page_title }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE RENDERED PAGE META DESCRIPTION IS:</h1> {{ page_description }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY COLLECTION TITLE IS:</h1> {{ collection.title }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY COLLECTION HANDLE IS:</h1> {{ collection.handle }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY COLLECTION ID IS:</h1> {{ collection.id }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY COLLECTION DESCRIPTION IS:</h1> {{ collection.description }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY PRODUCT TITLE IS:</h1> {{ product.title }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY PRODUCT HANDLE IS:</h1> {{ product.handle }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY PRODUCT ID IS:</h1> {{ product.id }}</span>
    <span><h1>THIS IS WHAT THE SHOPIFY PRODUCT DESCRIPTION IS:</h1> {{ product.description }}</span>
</div>
```